# Invite Registered Users to vote in voting app

Tags: django, foreign-keys, many-to-many, formsets

I'm trying to expand the Django tutorial for a school project and make it into a more usable voting app.

What I want is to allow users to create Polls and invite other registered users by email to vote on their Poll. Only the invited users will be allowed to vote.

My `models.py`:

```
class Poll(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published', auto_now_add=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    activation_date = models.DateTimeField('Activation Date', blank=True, null=True)
    expiration_date = models.DateTimeField('Expiration Date', blank=True, null=True)
    public_key = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    hash = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text

    def was_published_recently(self):
        now = timezone.now()
        return now - datetime.timedelta(days=1) <= self.pub_date <= now
    was_published_recently.admin_order_field = 'pub_date'
    was_published_recently.boolean = True
    was_published_recently.short_description = 'Published recently?'


class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Poll, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.choice_text


class EligibleVoters(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    poll = models.ForeignKey(Poll, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    email = models.EmailField(null=True)
```

I have a `Poll` table which contains the Poll Title and other information regarding the Poll. I also created a separate `Choices` table (like in the tutorial) which has a `ForeignKey` to the `Poll` table and contains the poll choices.
I figured that in order to invite users as eligible voters I needed a third table with `ForeignKeys` to the `Poll` and `User` tables. So i created one.

I should note that I'm using the build-in user model.

Here's my `views.py`:

```
class NewPoll(CreateView):
    model = Poll
    fields = ['question_text', 'is_active', 'activation_date', 'expiration_date']
    success_url = reverse_lazy('voting:index')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        data = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.POST:
            data['choices'] = ChoiceFormSet(self.request.POST)
            # data['eligible_voters_poll'] = EligibleVotersFormSetPoll(self.request.POST)
            # data['eligible_voters_user'] = EligibleVotersFormSetUser(self.request.POST)
            #data['eligible_voters'] = EligibleVotersFormSet(self.request.POST)
        else:
            data['choices'] = ChoiceFormSet()
        #     data['eligible_voters_poll'] = EligibleVotersFormSetPoll()
        #     data['eligible_voters_user'] = EligibleVotersFormSetUser()
        #    data['eligible_voters'] = EligibleVotersFormSet()
        return data

    def form_valid(self, form):
        context = self.get_context_data()
        choices = context['choices']
        # eligible_voters_poll = context['eligible_voters_poll']
        # eligible_voters_user = context['eligible_voters_user']
        #eligible_voters = context['eligible_voters']
        with transaction.atomic():
            self.object = form.save()
            if choices.is_valid():
                choices.instance = self.object
                choices.save()
            # if eligible_voters_poll.is_valid() and eligible_voters_user.is_valid():
            #     eligible_voters_poll.instance = self.object
            #     eligible_voters_poll.save()
            #     eligible_voters_user.instance = self.object
            #     eligible_voters_user.save()
            #if eligible_voters.is_valid():
            #    eligible_voters.instance = self.object
            #    eligible_voters.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

I have commented the lines that are previous attempt into making it work. Without the commented lines the user is able to create a poll and also create choices. I'm having trouble making the invite part working though.

Here is my `forms.py`:

```
class PollForm(ModelForm):
    activation_date = forms.DateTimeField(required=False)
    expiration_date = forms.DateTimeField(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Poll
        fields = ['question_text', 'is_active', 'activation_date', 'expiration_date']


class ChoiceForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Choice
        exclude = ['votes']


ChoiceFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Poll, Choice, form=ChoiceForm, extra=1)


def form_maker(parent2):
    class EligibleVotersForm(ModelForm):
        # def __init__(self, user, poll, *args, **kwargs):
        #     self.user = user
        #     self.poll = poll
        #     super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        def save(self, commit=True):
            instance = super(EligibleVotersForm, self).save(commit=False)
            # instance.parent1 = parent1
            instance.parent2 = parent2
            if commit:
                instance.save()
            return instance

        class Meta:
            model = EligibleVoters
            fields = ['email']
    return EligibleVotersForm


# EligibleVotersFormSetPoll = inlineformset_factory(Poll, EligibleVoters, form=EligibleVotersForm, extra=1)
# EligibleVotersFormSetUser = inlineformset_factory(User, EligibleVoters, form=EligibleVotersForm, extra=1)
# EligibleVotersFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Poll, EligibleVoters, form=form_maker(User), extra=1)
```

Here I have commented out again the lines that belong to my failed attempts at making it work. The closer I got it to working is to be able to invite by any email (not just the registered ones, which is what I want) and fill the `EligibleVoters` table with the emails associated with the `poll_id`. The `user_id` column though remained, empty.

Here's my html file:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
{% load static %}
  <h2>Poll Creation</h2>
<div class="col-md-4">
  <form action='' method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}

    <table class="table">
        {{ choices.management_form }}

        {% for form in choices.forms %}
            {% if forloop.first %}
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
                        <th>{{ field.label|capfirst }}</th>
                    {% endfor %}
                </tr>
                </thead>
            {% endif %}
            <tr class="{% cycle 'row1' 'row2' %} formset_row1">
                {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
                    <td>
                        {% if forloop.first %}
                            {% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
                                {{ hidden }}
                            {% endfor %}
                        {% endif %}
                        {{ field.errors.as_ul }}
                        {{ field }}
                    </td>
                {% endfor %}
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
    <table class="table">
        {{ eligible_voters.management_form }}

        {% for form in eligible_voters.forms %}
            {% if forloop.first %}
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
                        <th>{{ field.label|capfirst }}</th>
                    {% endfor %}
                </tr>
                </thead>
            {% endif %}
            <tr class="{% cycle 'row1' 'row2' %} formset_row2">
                {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
                    <td>
                        {% if forloop.first %}
                            {% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
                                {{ hidden }}
                            {% endfor %}
                        {% endif %}
                        {{ field.errors.as_ul }}
                        {{ field }}
                    </td>
                {% endfor %}
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="Save"/> <a href="{% url 'voting:index' %}">back to the list</a>
    </form>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="{% static 'voting/js/jquery.formset.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $('.formset_row1').formset({
            addText: 'add poll choice',
            deleteText: 'remove',
            prefix: 'choice_set'
        });
        $('.formset_row2').formset({
            addText: 'add eligible voter',
            deleteText: 'remove',
            prefix: 'eligiblevoters_set'
        });
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

Any ideas on how to make it work and only allow he eligible voters to vote for the polls they are invited to?
I was thinking that maybe my `EligibleVoters` model is wrong somehow and I need a `ManyToMany` field somewhere??

Comment: Please tidy up your code before posting, there's no reason to have all those commented-out lines.

Comment: I included these lines to show what I have already tried and didn't work. Maybe I was doing something wrong and someone will point it out. I didn't remove the commented-out lines because I think I was close to something and someone maybe can finish the solution instead of suggesting one from the start.